# CodeIgniter Database 'autoinit' not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We've recently aquired a new development server, and after moving all of our files over to the new server we have been experiencing an inability to connect to MySQL through CodeIgniter.

All of the login details worked, permissions were correct, etc.

I've found that setting `$db['master']['autoinit']` from `true` to `false` fixes this issue and the connection works.

I know that the autoinit setting determines whether or not to connect to the database prior to the first query being ran, but my question is why would it work on our old development server, and our production server, but not on the new development server?

The difference in MySQL version is going from `5.1.47` to `5.1.71`

Any ideas on what would cause the `autoinit` to fail would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, there must of been a problem in the transfer of `mysql.user` from one database to another, as when I dropped the user table and manually entered the users, the CodeIgniter `autoinit` configuration worked when set to true.